# changing div element to canvas issue in html2canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html2canvas

Using [html2Canvas](https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas/releases) , I can change body element to canvas in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hpaLB/2/) ,

```
  html2canvas(document.body, {
        onrendered: function(canvas) {
            document.body.appendChild(canvas);
        }
    });
```

but when I get div element by ID using [this code](http://jsfiddle.net/hpaLB/3/) ,

```
  html2canvas($('#mainDiv'), {
            onrendered: function(canvas) {
                document.body.appendChild(canvas);
            }
        });
```

I can't change this div to canvas . How can I fix it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you ensure that jQuery is included in your `jsFiddle`, rendering the element works as intended. [Here's a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hpaLB/5/).